# Blinking cursor issue in Ubuntu Server 11.04

Tags: linux, unix

Just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and booted into it.  It booted straight into the terminal so I edited `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
and changed it to `quiet splash`
When i ran the reboot command, all I get is a black screen with a blinking cursor.  I have read a decent amount but can't seem to find a solution to this specific problem, any help would be awesome.
Specs

Optiplex 755 with 2.66 ghz processor

Comment: What graphics card do you have in the machine? This sounds like a potential problem with the graphics card and lack of compatibility with it. Depending on the card you may be able to install a set of drivers while in command-line mode to get the graphics to work properly. BTW, I have to ask: why 11.04? I would go with 12.04 LTS at the very least or 13.04 for the latest. 11.04 has reached end of life and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

> It booted straight into the terminal

So it boots before.

> When i ran the reboot command, all I get is a black screen with a
>   blinking cursor.

That means it no longer boot any more.

Are you sure that's the only thing that you changed? If you change it back, would you be able to boot into terminal again? If not, you need to reinstall grub again.

```
grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/sdbx /dev/sdbx
```

If you want to install grub into PBR (better than installing to MBR, IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Boot with [Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) or [Rescatux](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/)
2. Browse the options of the boot disk trying to boot your installed Ubuntu
3. Once you get the login screen enter to the system and run this `sudo update-grub`
4. Reboot

If that don't worked do the same steps, but after step 3 do this:

run `mount`

You will get a list with mounted devices. You need to look for the one which says where is mount the / directory; something like `/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)`.

Take care with this, and re-read it until you understand it.

We were looking for the /dev/sda1 part, but it can be /dev/xvda1, or /dev/hda1 or with a different number like /dev/sda5.

**Remove the last number** /dev/sda**1** -> /dev/sda.

Run this: `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`